# Communication between two spring controllers from different spring applications deployed into single tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, war, spring-4

I have few spring applications deployed into single tomcat server. Those applications are part of single WAR. Each application has it's own dispatcher servlet with respective controllers behind of it.

I have use case where communication between those applications are needed. What is the optimal way to do this? Will be it ok to use rest template here?